# Counting records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Take a look at this SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetRecTitleVeh] 

AS
BEGIN
select 
    a.StockNo, c.ClaimNo,
    v.VIN, v.[Year],v.Make, v.Model,
    c.DOAssign, t.DOLoss, t.RecTitleDate
From 
    dbo.Assignments a,
    dbo.Assignment_ClaimInfo c,
    dbo.Assignment_TitleInfo t,
    dbo.Assignment_VehicleInfo v
Where 
    a.AssignmentID= c.AssignmentID and
    c.AssignmentID= t.AssignmentID and
    t.AssignmentID= v.AssignmentID and
    t.RecTitleDate is not null and
    c.InsuranceComp = 'XYZ' and
    a.StockNo not in (select StockNo from dbo.Invoice where InvoiceType = 'Payment Invoice') 
order by t.RecTitleDate
END
```

This SP works fine and gives me required result.

What i need is to ask that is there any shortest way to count records obtained by executing this SP. For ex. i am trying like this

```
select count(*) from sp_GetRecTitleVeh
```

I know that there is a solution like -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CountRecTitleVeh] 

AS
BEGIN
select 
    count(a.StockNo)
From 
    dbo.Assignments a,
    dbo.Assignment_ClaimInfo c,
    dbo.Assignment_TitleInfo t,
    dbo.Assignment_VehicleInfo v
Where 
    a.AssignmentID= c.AssignmentID and
    c.AssignmentID= t.AssignmentID and
    t.AssignmentID= v.AssignmentID and
    t.RecTitleDate is not null and
    c.InsuranceComp = 'XYZ' and
    a.StockNo not in (select StockNo from dbo.Invoice where InvoiceType = 'Payment Invoice') 
order by t.RecTitleDate
END
```

Do you have any idea how could i count records got by executing SP.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
EXEC sp_GetRecTitleVeh 
SELECT @@Rowcount
```

Comment: note that this isn't such good idea. if you add a single command after the select in your stored procedure this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

**immediately** after your select do select @@rowcount. this will give you the number of affected rows.

also start using the proper join syntax. the old syntax for left (*=) and right jons (=*) is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Mladen!!! Do you think there is any speed improvement using INNER JOIN instead of = operators?

Comment: speed no, readability yes. not to mention the old sysnatx won't work in new versions of sql server.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `@@rowcount` is the preferred approach.

But, just for the record, if you handle the `SqlCommand.StatementCompleted` event, you can get the `DONE_IN_PROC` message which is returned to the client. That includes the number of rows affected. But you can't use `SET NOCOUNT ON` if you want to get `DONE_IN_PROC`, so performance will be hindered a bit if you do this.